# Magento rounds up the custom product price

Tags: magento

I'm setting a custom price depending on each customer. Using a webservice I receive the specific price for each customer in the format: XX,DD

When I use the function setprice in order to set the new price for the product:

```
$product->setFinalPrice($price);
```

Magento rounds up the price and, for example, if the $price is 38,50, then it sets the product price to 38. I've tried changing the ',' for '.' with str_replace, but in this case, it seems it can't set up the price.

How can I tell Magento to use the decimals as well?

Thanks

Comment: Does `$price` print out correctly?

Comment: Yes, it does in both cases (when it is 38.50 and 38,50). But Magento seems to convert that price rounding it up...

Answer (score 2):

First you should convert your price to decimal number:

```
$value="38,50";
$amount = Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber($value,array('locale'=>'nl_NL'));
// or you can use str_replace
```

In Magento products has two types of standard price:

```
$product->getPrice();
$product->getSpecialPrice();
```

finalPrice - it is not actually product value, it will be calculated by Magento based on price, special_price, tier price and so on. You should set price value and save the product:

```
$value = "38,50"; //this decimalformat is used in nl_Nl locale
$amount = Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber($value,array('locale'=>'nl_NL'));
$amount = Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($amount); //round price based on Magento logic
$product->setPrice($amount); //price - is actual value of product
// some extra code here
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in that you can use:

```
echo number_format($_product->getPrice(), 2)
```

It will give you a couple of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you do not want the price to round up. If that is the case then your solution depends on the version of PHP you are using.

PHP 5.3 you can simply use the round function to round it down like so:

```
round($price, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

If you are using PHP 5.2 you do not have the luxary of the PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN so you have to put the following function in somewhere (a helper makes the most sense to me) and call it:

```
floor($line_item_price * 100) / 100;
```

What this does is first multiply the value with 100 and then floor the value. This gives you a rounded down value with the precision of 2. Then divide by 100 to get the correct value.

The number 100 comes from the power(10, desired precision)

I hope you are on PHP 5.3. I did not enjoy having to do the PHP 5.2 solution very much.

Answer (score 0):

To round up a price in magento you need overwrite a directory/currency model method convert.

```
Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::convert()
```

here you will find like this

```
return $price*$rate
```

and need to set like this

```
 return round($price*$rate);
```